# How to check the rdf file imported in Neo4j?

Tags: graph, neo4j, rdf

I have imported a rdf file in Neo4j.

```java
CALL semantics.importRDF("file:///Users/wuhaosen123/Desktop/kg4openkg.rdf","RDF/XML", { shortenUrls: false, typesToLabels: true, commitSize: 9000 })
```

But the results are just a table , a text , and a code label. There is no label named "Graph".

I create a easy example :

```java
create (n:Person{name:"d"}),(m:Person{name:"e"})
create (n)-[:R{type:"fathe and son"}]->(m)
return n
```

There is a return value  that can be described by Graph.

But I can't find the grammar that visual the rdf Graph.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. When I import the rdf file, the nodes has been imported the database. It needs us to click the first label, then it will appear the nodes that you has created or imported.